# Why is this html code not correctly interpreted?

Tags: php, html, rendering

I am a bit curious about this HTML code (Firebug's view):

```
<td>1&#8211;1 of 1 record found matching your query (<a href="rss.php?where=title%20RLIKE%20%22physics%22" title="track newly added records matching your current query by subscribing to this RSS feed">RSS</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="query_history.php" title="recall a previous query from your current session">history</a>):</td>
```

I was trying to install refbase. I used the snapshot version because of SQL problems with the current release. While testing I got this view (Firebug console is opened on purpose to show how the code is interpreted, but I see the same on chromium for instance):

.

[image: view with code not interpreted correctly]

.

Then I clicked in the firebug view and added a single `space` character somewhere, and did escape to let it as it was. But after having added the `space`, the view changed into this:

.

[image]

.

So basically I changed nothing but the code is now correctly interpreted. That's really weird. I googled a bit about this, but I think I might not have found the appropriate keywords.

Could someone explain me the reason behind this weird behaviour and how to fix it? BTW this [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/refbase/code/HEAD/tree/branches/bleeding-edge/search.php) is the complete php source producing this page. Look on line 796.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to LGSon I noticed that it is a Firebug's trap: it interprets the `&amp;` stuff to show nice html code and then when you edit-it, it becomes the real code. That's tricky indeed, but when checking page source you can see the real HTML:

```
<td>1&amp;#8211;1 of 1 record found matching your query (&lt;a href=&quot;rss.php?where=title%20RLIKE%20%22physics%22&quot; title=&quot;track newly added records matching your current query by subscribing to this RSS feed&quot;&gt;RSS&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;|&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;query_history.php&quot; title=&quot;recall a previous query from your current session&quot;&gt;history&lt;/a&gt;):</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `1&#8211;1`

Sample

```html
1&#8211;1
```

Comment: my mistake, I used firebug's `copy HTML` functionality and it transformed the `&` into `&amp;` but that is not present in the screenshot for instance.

Comment: But I think there should be something to dig further from this. Firebug may have tricked me by interpreting the &amp; stuff in its html view

Comment: @Aldian Well I think so, as the pre edit version `1&amp;#8211;1` would make sence to become like that, but not my posted one ... I'll leave it for now and if you find something else, let me know and I will delete this answer (or adjust)

Comment: I found out that you are right on the mark. I am going to edit a bit to make things clearer and then accept your answer. Thanks for pointing out the problem